# PHP string to nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to convert a string from an ldap query. I am querying my Active Directory server for user accounts. This is the string that I pulled.

```
"CN=Phil Robertson,OU=Users,OU=Duck Commander,OU=Department & Buildings,DC=OCSDtest,DC=local"
```

I would want it converted to an array that looks like this

```
 $array['local']['OCtest']['Department & Buildings']['Duck Commander']['Users']['Phil Robertson']=1;
```

NOT

```
$array( [1]=>'local,[2]=>'OCtest',[3]='Depart',[4]='Duck Commander',[5]='Users');
```

So far I have

Example code ---

```
   $dnn2 = ldap_explode_dn("CN=Phil Robertson,OU=Users,OU=Duck Commander,OU=Department &       Buildings,DC=OCSDtest,DC=local",1);
    unset($dnn2['count']);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(array_reverse($dnn2));
```

What am I needing?

Comment: You want a 6-dimensional array, or an array with 6 elements?

Comment: 6-dimensional array. When I add other users, it would be added to the array. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dnn2 = ldap_explode_dn("CN=Phil Robertson,OU=Users,OU=Duck Commander,OU=Department &       Buildings,DC=OCSDtest,DC=local",1);
unset($dnn2['count']);
$result = null;
$ref =& $result;
foreach (array_reverse($dnn2) as $dn) {
    $ref = array($dn => null);
    $ref =& $ref[$dn];
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $arrayvalue = array();
    foreach($dnn2 as $dn)
    {
       $temp  = explode('=',$dn);
       $temp1 =  substr($temp[1], 0, strpos($temp1[1], ',')); 
       $arrayvalue[]  = $temp1;
    }

    print_r($arrayvalue);
```

Comment: `ldap_explode_dn()` already removes the part before `=`, you don't need to split it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$a = array();
foreach($dnn2 as $dn)
{
   $arr = explode('=',$dn);
   $a[] = $arr[1];  //or $a[] = array($arr[1]); for 6 dimensional array
}

print_r($a);
```

Comment: This just makes a array( [1]="item",[2]="item"). I am looking for array['item']['item']['item'].

Comment: Should be `$a[] = array($arr[1]);`